# Angular 7 promises are working strang? going success block, errror block at a time

Tags: angular, angular-promise, angular7, angular-httpclient

I am converting my application Angular 2(Http) to Angular 7(HttpClient)
I am not understanding why this working like that. my code

```
     service.ts

  return this.http.get(serviceUrl).toPromise().then((data:any) => {
            return data;
        })
```

component.ts

```
this.myService.getList()
    .then((rmanFmvRulesDefList: any) => {
      $.unblockUI();
      console.log('list',rmanFmvRulesDefList);
      this.datasource = rmanFmvRulesDefList.content;
      this.rmanFmvRulesDefList = rmanFmvRulesDefList.content;


      if (this.rmanFmvRulesDefList.length > 0) {

        for (let i = 0; i < rmanFmvRulesDefList.content.length; i++) {
          this.rmanFmvRulesDefList1.push({
            'fmvRuleName':  rmanFmvRulesDefList.content[i].fmvRuleName,
            'fmvCategory':  rmanFmvRulesDefList.content[i].fmvCategory
          })
        }

        /*  for (let i = 0; i < rmanFmvRulesDefList.content.length; i++) {
        this.rmanFmvRulesDefList1.push({
          'fmvRuleName':  rmanFmvRulesDefList.content[i].fmvRuleName,
          'fmvCategory':  rmanFmvRulesDefList.content[i].fmvCategory,
          'fmvType': rmanFmvRulesDefList.content[i].fmvType,
          'fmvRuleStatus':  rmanFmvRulesDefList.content[i].fmvRuleStatus,
          'fmvPrice':  rmanFmvRulesDefList.content[i].fmvPrice ,
          'min':  formatNumber(rmanFmvRulesDefList.content[i].min , '1.2-2'),
          'median': formatNumber(rmanFmvRulesDefList.content[i].median , '1.2-2'),
          'max': formatNumber(rmanFmvRulesDefList.content[i].max , '1.2-2')
        })
      }*/ 
      }

      console.log(this.rmanFmvRulesDefList1, 'rman fm list')

    }).catch((err: any) => {
      console.log('erre block')
          this.growlMsgs=[{severity:'error', summary:'Error Message', detail:'Error occured while getting data!!'}];
           $.unblockUI();
       });
```

from my service I am getting 100 list items

Issue: My success(then), error(then) block calling at a time in such a scenarion

1. If I prepare the array( this.rmanFmvRulesDefList1) with  two properties it's working fine

   **2. But If I prepare the array with 8 properties it going in catch block ,and execute the code**

   Please any one help me what happened here

Comment: Please simplify your code and make it more readable to make it easier for us to understand what the real problem is. What i can say now is: try to use .subscribe instead of .toPromise.  Try to make the code that has the unexpected behavior as small as possible.

Comment: Ya, I resolve my issue, actually problem is not with the promises, while pushing I am using formatNumber pipe with wrong syntax